# use two expandablelistView in the same Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I want to use to different expandAbleListView in the same layout, but the view dose not complete i can't see my child content if i used both, but if i hash one of them i can see content and it's work prefectly..

here is my xml :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/background"
>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_below="@id/techScrolView">


<ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/addRequiedEmployee"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:cacheColorHint="@color/white"
    android:layout_below="@id/techScrolView"
    android:background="@color/background"

    />

<ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/addRequiedEmployee2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/addRequiedEmployee"
    android:background="@color/background"
    />

</LinearLayout>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/top_bar_backgroung"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize">


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/topBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/top_bar_backgroung"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layoutDirection="rtl">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
            android:paddingBottom="2dp"
            android:paddingTop="2dp"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/logo" />

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>



    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/techScrolView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@color/background">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@color/background">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal">

            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                android:id="@+id/profileDisplayImg"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/circle"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/hint_image"
                android:textSize="@dimen/hint_size" />

        </RelativeLayout>


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/profileName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/profile_text_size" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/profilePlace"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/map_marker_white"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/profile_text_size" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>
```

i don't know where is the issue exactly.

Comment: Both expandable list view height should not be match_parent try using other value like 250dp or 300 dp..

Comment: @Arjun thanks, but you sure that is perfect solution ?